# Using OpenMPI to broadcast data happened deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

I wrote a program in Java which call OpenMPI in single thread for communication. **Isend/recv** is used to prevent deadlock. The caller invoke send method and then, all send request put in queue. The network thread get request from queue to sent.

```
class NetworkThread extends Thread {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<SendRequest> sendQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final List<Request> activeSends = new LinkedList<>();
    private final List<RecvRequest> recvList = new LinkedList<>();
    private volatile boolean shutdown;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("network thread started");
        try {
            loop();
        } catch (MPIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void loop() throws MPIException {
        while (!shutdown) {
            Status status = MPI.COMM_WORLD.iProbe(MPI.ANY_SOURCE, MPI.ANY_TAG);
            if (status != null) {
                int source = status.getSource();
                int tag = status.getTag();
                int sizeInBytes = status.getCount(MPI.BYTE);

                ByteBuffer buffer = MPI.newByteBuffer(sizeInBytes);
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(buffer, sizeInBytes, MPI.BYTE, source, tag);
                byte[] data = new byte[sizeInBytes];
                buffer.get(data);
                RecvRequest recvRequest = new RecvRequest(data, source, tag);
                synchronized (recvList) {
                    recvList.add(recvRequest);
                }
            }

            SendRequest sendRequest;
            while ((sendRequest = sendQueue.poll()) != null) {
                byte[] data = sendRequest.getData();
                ByteBuffer buffer = MPI.newByteBuffer(data.length);
                buffer.put(data);
                Request request = MPI.COMM_WORLD.iSend(buffer, data.length, MPI.BYTE, sendRequest.getDest(), sendRequest.getTag());
                synchronized (activeSends) {
                    activeSends.add(request);
                }
            }
            //delete sent record
            synchronized (activeSends) {
                Iterator<Request> iterator = activeSends.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Request request = iterator.next();
                    if (request.test())
                        iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void send(byte[] data, int dest, int tag) {
        SendRequest sendRequest = new SendRequest(data, dest, tag);
            sendQueue.add(sendRequest);
    }

    public byte[] read(int source, int tag) {
        byte[] data;
        while ((data = tryRead(source, tag)) == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public byte[] tryRead(int source, int tag) {
        byte[] data = null;
        synchronized (recvList) {
            Iterator<RecvRequest> iterator = recvList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                RecvRequest recvRequest = iterator.next();
                if (recvRequest.getSource() == source && recvRequest.getTag() == tag) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    data = recvRequest.getData();
                    break;//just get one
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
        //waiting for all sent
        synchronized (activeSends) {
            while (activeSends.size() > 0)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}

class SendRequest {
    private byte[] data;
    private int dest;
    private int tag;

    SendRequest(byte[] data, int dest, int tag) {
        this.data = data;
        this.dest = dest;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public int getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public int getDest() {
        return dest;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

class RecvRequest {
    private byte[] data;
    private int source;
    private int tag;

    RecvRequest(byte[] data, int source, int tag) {
        this.data = data;
        this.source = source;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public int getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public int getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I also wrote a test case which implemented broadcast data to every process for five times in random time interval (except myself and master). Hopefully, all process will finish the send/receive task then exit.

```
public class BroadcastTest {
    private static final int TAG_MPI = 123;
    static int rank;
    static String host;

    static {
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MPIException, InterruptedException, UnknownHostException {
        MPI.Init(args);
        int rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getRank();
        int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getSize();
        BroadcastTest.rank = rank;
        if (rank == 0) {
            System.out.println(String.format("total %d machines", size));
            System.out.println("master started");
        } else {
            NetworkThread networkThread = new NetworkThread();
            networkThread.start();

            Thread sendTh = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000)); //send data five times in random interval
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for (int machineId = 1/* skip master */; machineId < size; machineId++) {
                        if (machineId == rank) continue;//skip myself
                        networkThread.send(new byte[4096], machineId, TAG_MPI); //send 4K bytes data
                    }
                }
            });
            //receive data
            Thread recvTh = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    for (int machineId = 1; machineId < size; machineId++) {
                        if (machineId == rank) continue;
                        byte[] bytes = networkThread.read(machineId, TAG_MPI);
                    }
                }
            });
            sendTh.start();
            recvTh.start();
            sendTh.join();
            recvTh.join();
            networkThread.shutdown();
            networkThread.join();
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("%s exit", host));
        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

COMMAND LINE:

```
/home/gongsf/openmpi-2.1.2/bin/mpirun --prefix /home/gongsf/openmpi-2.1.2 -bycore -nooversubscribe -machinefile /home/gongsf/JavaMPI/myhosts /home/gongsf/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -classpath /home/gongsf/JavaMPI/lib/*:/home/gongsf/JavaMPI/out/production/JavaMPI BroadcastTest
```

**QUESTION:** This program works fine at lower processes e.g. slots=4. But when increase the slots or data size to send, the program enter **deadlock** state occasionally. I tried to alter the OpenMPI version (3.0, 2.1.2, 1.7.5), but seems doesn't work.

Comment: at first glance, there seems to be a race condition in the shutdown process.
you should complete all the queues (e.g. send and receive everything) before exiting.

Comment: Yes, the statement "shutdown = true" should execute below the "while code block". After fix, the problem still happeded. I added some output statements to figure out which line stuck in.             
    sendTh.start();
    recvTh.start();
    sendTh.join();
    recvTh.join();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s - %d before exit", host,rank));
    networkThread.shutdown();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s - %d after exit", host,rank));
    networkThread.join();

Comment: The results shows that all process output "xxxx - xx before exit", but some process stuck in "networkThread.shutdown();". This is strange because all process received data, so the activeSends list should be empty. Thus, no process should stuck in "while code block" @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: i added a `printf()` like at the end of `NetworkThread.run()` and though all non master ranks reach there, not all the ranks can `join()` their `NetworkThread`. that could point to a memory corruption.

Comment: I know very little about the java MPI bindings, and the documentation I found is terrible. Are you sure that the `buffer` passed to `MPI.COMM_WORLD.iSend` will be kept alive the whole time during the request? Also you should somehow request and confirm that your thread level is at least `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`.

Comment: @Zulan Thank you for your apply, I look up the **Isend** implementation, the reference of ByteBuffer pass to a **native** method called "iSend". Thus, the ByteBuffer should not be recycled by GC. I also tried init MPI with MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED flag, the program can terminated at most time with lower process number (2 machines, total 19 processes).  This may caused by poor switch device (100M bandwith Switch).